# Categories link showing Prdocut detail view instead showing list of categories

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using Django generic views for an ecommerce project. When I created Categories the detail view for it not showing list of Categories instead it directly takes me to the first product.

My models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(active=True)

class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_queryset().active()

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)
    objects = ProductManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product_detail", kwargs={"pk":self.pk})
def image_upload_to(instance, filename):
    title = instance.product.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    file_extension = filename.split(".")[1]
    new_filename = "%s.%s"%(instance.id, file_extension)
    return 'products/%s/%s' %(slug, new_filename)


class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_price(self):
        if self.sale_price is not None:
            return self.sale_price
        else:
            return self.price

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.product.get_absolute_url()

def post_save_signal_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    product = instance
    variations = product.variation_set.all()
    if variations.count() == 0:
        new_var = Variation()
        new_var.product = product
        new_var.title = "Original Product"
        new_var.price = product.price
        new_var.save()
post_save.connect(post_save_signal_receiver, sender=Product)

def image_upload_to(instance, filename):
    title = instance.product.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    file_extension = filename.split(".")[1]
    new_filename = "%s.%s"%(instance.id, file_extension)
    return 'products/%s/%s' %(slug, new_filename)


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product.title


class Category(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("category_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug })
```

My views:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, Http404, redirect
from django.db.models import Q
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import Product, Variation, Category
from .forms import VariationInventoryFormSet
from .mixins import StaffRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin




class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    template_name = "products/product_list.html"

class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category


class VariationListView(StaffRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Variation
    queryset = Variation.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(VariationListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["formset"] = VariationInventoryFormSet(queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

        product_pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        if product_pk:
            product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_pk)
            queryset = Variation.objects.filter(product=product)
        return queryset

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = VariationInventoryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save(commit=False)
            for form in formset:

                new_item = form.save(commit=False)
                if new_item.title:
                    product_pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
                    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_pk)
                    new_item.product = product
                    new_item.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Form Updated')
            return redirect('products')
        raise Http404



class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["query"] = self.request.GET.get("q")
        return context
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            qs = self.model.objects.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query) |
                Q(description__icontains=query)
                )
            try:
                qs2 = self.model.objects.filter(
                    Q(price=query)
                )
                qs = (qs | qs2).distinct()
            except:
                pass
        return qs
```

I've rendered product_list.html for view as you can see in CategoryListView above:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block jumbotron %}
{% include 'jumbotron.html' %}
{% endblock jumbotron %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
    <tr>{% for object in object_list %}
    <td><a href="{% url 'detail' pk=object.pk %}">{{ object.title }}</a></td>

        <td>{{ product.description }}</td>
    </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

My category_detail view is like:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h2>{{ object ))</h2>

<table class="table">
    {% for product in object.product_set.all %}

    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.title }}</a> </td>
{% endfor %}

    </tr>

</table>

{% endblock content %}
```

My Category urls are:

```
url(r'^$', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='categories'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_detail'),
```

I can see categories fine at `localhost:8000/categories` but when I click on the link it takes me to single product page instead of list of categories.

My root URLS are:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import (
    base
    )

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),# Name space makes your urls unique even if they are of same name in multiple apps
    url(r'products/', include('products.urls')),
    url(r'categories/', include('products.urls_categories')),
    url(r'^$', base, name='home'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: You should show the rest of your urls.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I've added root urls above.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. What link are you clicking on, which view do you expect to see, and which view do you see instead?

Comment: When I click categories then it works fine but when I select one of the category it takes me to first product directly but what it should do is to show me list of products in that category. Logically I couldn't make sense out of it that why it is doing this. In Category list view I've added Category.objects.all() as queryset. Still instead of taking me to list it forwards me to a single product. Simply I need to see list in detail view for categories and it is showing me a single product instead.

Comment: No, sorry, you need to be specific. There's a lot of code above, and I'm not sure which bits you're referring to. **Which** link do you click? What URL does that go to? Which view are you expecting to serve that page? Which view is actually serving it instead?

Comment: I goto "locathost:8000/products" it shows me products. I click one of the product detail and it takes me to product so that part is fine. I pass the address "localhost:8000/categories" it shows me categories. Now the only problem is that when I click on any category for detail view but it does not show me list of items in it. Instead it takes me to first product detail page in that list. Problem is with Category detail view only and rest of the code is just fine. I've pasted the code to give complete picture of what I am doing.